# Empty cell from excel into pandas df

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

After  `.read_excel()`, I am trying to use `.isin()` but need to include empty cells for a particular column. How is the data manipulated? I read that its a NaN but also found out that `NaN != NaN`. How do I access the empty excel cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
import numpy as np
df = df.fillna(np.nan)
df.isin(['test','t2', np.nan])
```

depending on the type of NaN you are getting you might not have to use the `df.fillna(np.nan)` but I would recommand doing it anyway.

Comment: It does work...but i cannot use numpy because it turns account numbers into dollary(?) values. i.e. it makes an account number 0009800 -> 9800.00 or something like that